# How many superdelegates have endorsed voting for the plurality delegate winner to be the nominee?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, primaries, democratic-party, democratic-primary

On Wednesday’s Democratic Presidential Debate in Nevada, candidates were asked if they think that whoever gets a plurality of the pledged delegates should ultimately become the Democratic nominee, even if they haven’t gotten a majority as the rules require.  Only Bernie Sanders said yes to that, which is unsurprising given that he currently seems most likely to become the plurality delegate winner.

But the ones who will ultimately decide whether that principle is followed are the delegates themselves.  How the process works is that if no one gets a pledged delegate majority on the first ballot, the pledged delegates get unbound and then they along with the superdelegates try to form a majority behind a candidate in subsequent ballots.  They could coalesce around the one who got a plurality on the first ballot, but they could also coalesce around one of the runners up, or even around a candidate not in the race.

Now no pledged delegates have been selected yet.  But my question is, have any superdelegates endorsed this principle that the plurality delegate winner should win the nomination?  If so, how many?

Comment: I don't expect that we'll hear very much from superdelegates unless and until it's clear that the convention will be brokered.

Comment: @JoeC Many superdelegates are TV pundits, prominent politicians, etc., so I think at least some of them may have weighed in.

Comment: There is an article on wikipedia attempting to track the endorsements given by various superdelegates.  But of course superdelegates may freely change their minds for any reason at any time.  Some presumably already have.  So anything they've said or not said at this point is somewhat moot.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_2020_Democratic_Party_automatic_delegates

Comment: Lots of comments deleted. Please remember that the goal of comments should be to **improve the question**, not to discuss its subject matter. Please read [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) before you engage in comment debates.